# jQuery Validate plugin custom method message not toggling

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following rule I created:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("onespecial", function(value, element){
        var pattern = /^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=]).*$/;

        return (pattern.test(value));

    }, "Your password must contain one number or special character");
```

and enable it by using the following in the validate constructor:

```
  password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                onespecial: true
            },
```

To check to see if the user had entered one special char or a number in their PW.  If I enter 6 characters that are all letters, it throws the message "Your password must contain one number or special character".  If I then add a special char or number, the error message does not go away, even though when I click submit, the form validates just fine.  If I type in one go a 6 digit password with a number or special char, the error message never appears.  Anyone know why the message stays even after the password passes validation and how I can get rid of the message?

Edit:  Here's the HTML for the form:

```
 <form action="/" id="activateForm" method="post">      
 <div>
 <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-input" placeholder="First name" onfocus="this.placeholder=&#039;&#039;" onblur="this.placeholder=&#039;First name&#039;" id="FirstName" />
 </div>     
 <div>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-input" placeholder="Last name" onfocus="this.placeholder=&#039;&#039;" onblur="this.placeholder=&#039;Last name&#039;" id="LastName" />
 </div>
    <div>
 <input type="password" name="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder=&#039;&#039;" onblur="this.placeholder=&#039;Password&#039;" id="Password" />
 </div>
 <div>
 <input type="password" name="pass_confirm" class="form-input" placeholder="Confirm password" onfocus="this.placeholder=&#039;&#039;" onblur="this.placeholder=&#039;Confirm password&#039;" id="PassConfirm" />
 </div>     
 <div><input type="hidden" name="key" value="9480be862a441eba57f1904cbc3a78ce92989b0e" id="Key" />
 </div>       
 <input type="submit" value="Finish" class="button button-blue" />    
 </form>
```

and here's the JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("onespecial", function(value, element){
        var pattern = /^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=]).*$/;

        return (pattern.test(value));

    }, "Your password must contain one number or special character");

    $("#activateForm").validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                onespecial: true
            },
            pass_confirm: {
                equalTo: "#Password"
            },
            position: "required",
            category: "required"

        },
        messages: {
            first_name: "Please enter your first name",
            last_name: "Please enter your last name",
            pass_confirm: "Your passwords much match",
            position: "Please select your position",
            category: "Please select your category"
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/  ~ Your problem must be within code you've failed to show us.  Show a complete example. Where is the HTML for the form? Where is your call to `.validate()`?

Comment: @Sparky I added the code here in the OP after the Edit text.

Comment: Your code is still working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/1/

Comment: Which versions of the plugin and jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Sparky 1.11.1 is the version I'm using.

Comment: And which version of jQuery??  Again, the code you've posted is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/2/

Comment: If you'd just take a look at [the jsFiddle I posted](http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/2/), it's using your code, jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Validate v1.11.1.  The jsFiddle is working perfectly fine so I'm not sure what else we can do here.

Comment: @Sparky I really don't know what to say.  I've literally removed all the code from the page except for the includes, the form and the JS code and it still won't work for me.  There must be a reason.  It only has this issue on the custom regex rule, and if I log out the pattern it logs out true when I have the correct pattern..

Comment: I don't know what else to say either.  It works in the jsFiddle... does the jsFiddle work for you? What browser are you using?  Try a different one.

Comment: @Sparky I think I might have figured it out.  If I remove everything (even the CSS) it then hides the message.  Why?  I have no idea... I'm still investigating but it doesn't seem to be the plugin...

Comment: I already know it's _not_ the plugin.  Again, if you think it's a CSS issue, then show the CSS.  Edit my jsFiddle with your actual code so that the issue can be demonstrated.

Comment: (Not sure why you got a downvote: the question seems clear and well-organized. But I voted to close: jsfiddle also works for me, so it appears your problem is something else, not what you are asking.)

Comment: @DarrenCook Thanks Darren, agreed, don't know why I was downvoted.  I'm closing now.

Answer (score 1):

The code, as you've posted it, is working fine.  Make sure the rest of your code follows a valid working format such as the example below.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("onespecial", function (value, element) {
        var pattern = /^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=]).*$/;
        return (pattern.test(value));
    }, "Your password must contain one number or special character");


    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                onespecial: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

**EDIT**

Using the updated code from the OP along with jQuery 1.9.1 and Validate plugin version 1.11.1, everything is still working as it should:

http://jsfiddle.net/LCAf7/2/

Comment: I added the form code and JS code.  I see nothing wrong with them.  Any ideas?